# Javascript Click on HTML Element Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, click

I am scraping a website and at some point this element appears.

```
<button data-id="continue-button" class="odf-btn odf-btn-lg odf-btn-primary odf-btn-block continue_without_hotel">Continue without hotel</button>
```

Which I want to click via javascript.

```
document.querySelector('.continue_without_hotel').click()
```

For some unknown reason this doesn't do anything. I should clarify that I do this on other pages and it works, so there must be something strange here happening but no idea what could be.

Any thoughts on what could be happening?

Comment: are you waiting for the page to load first? then maybe placing a small delay? This button's actions might be getting setup on window.load or something?

Comment: I tested this on the console and it doesn’t work. Of course waiting until everything loads.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the following code

```js
document.querySelector('.continue_without_hotel').addEventListener("click", () => {
    // Handle click functionality
});
```

Let me know if that fixes it for you

Comment: The question is how to click the element, not adding a listener

Comment: Ah, now I understand, I tested what you currently have up top in your original question and it seems to be working fine for me.  Which then means that either the button isn't rendered by the time you click it, or it is erroring out somewhere else and doesn't execute the function the `click()` is in.  Can you provide the function and where it's being called?